# how to call a user defined function according to dropdown input in php?

Tags: php, html

I'm new with php.I have written a function fill_data($tagindex) now I want to call filldata(0); Input from a html form is a dropdownlist with AI-Types. I want it work like if i select AI-Type as eg.DTP4 then fill_data(0);fill_data(1);fill_data(2); should be called as result will be displayed accordingly.
My question is that how can i do it? Can anybody help??plz..
Below is my so far tried code..

```html
project.php

 function fill_data($tagindex)
        {
       $fromdate=$_POST['fromdate'];
                $todate=$_POST['todate'];
                $fromtime=$_POST['fromtime'];
                $totime=$_POST['totime'];
        // Create connection
              $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','test');
             // Check connection
               if (!$conn) 
             {
                 die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                }

                $sql ="SELECT * FROM floattable WHERE TagIndex=$tagindex AND (DateAndTime between '$fromdate .'  '. $fromtime' AND '$todate .'  '. $totime') ORDER BY DateAndTime ASC;";

                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
         try{
     
     //for IP
     if  (($tagindex=0)||($tagindex=1)||($tagindex=2)||($tagindex=3)||($tagindex=4)||($tagindex=5)||($tagindex=6)||($tagindex=7)||($tagindex=8)||($tagindex=10)||($tagindex=11)||($tagindex=12)||($tagindex=13)||($tagindex=14)||($tagindex=14)||($tagindex=15)||
      ($tagindex=16)||($tagindex=17)||($tagindex=18)||($tagindex=19)||($tagindex=20)||($tagindex=21)||($tagindex=22)||($tagindex=23)||($tagindex=24)||($tagindex=25)||($tagindex=26)||($tagindex=27)||($tagindex=28)||($tagindex=29)||($tagindex=30)||($tagindex=31)||($tagindex=32)||
      ($tagindex=33)||($tagindex=34)||($tagindex=35)||($tagindex=36)||($tagindex=37)||($tagindex=38)||($tagindex=39)||($tagindex=40))
      {
      // to display output
      echo "<table border='1' cellspacing='3' align='centre'>
        <tr>
        <th>DateAndTime</th>
        <th>Millitm</th>
        <th>TagIndex</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Market</th>
        </tr>";

         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
       {
        echo " <tr>
        <td>".$row['DateAndTime']."</td>
        <td>".$row['Millitm']."</td>
         <td>".$row['TagIndex']."</td>
          <td>".$row['Val']."</td>
        <td>".$row['Status']."</td>
         <td>".$row['Marker']."</td>
        </tr>";
       }
                 echo "</table>";
           }
              

          }
       catch (Exception $e)
       {
        echo $e->getmessage();
        exit(1);
       }
      mysqli_close($conn);
   
             }//End-of Fill_data Function   

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
 {
    
 $selected = $_POST['AI-Types'];


  if('what condition i should write here so that below three calls will be executed')
                        fill_data(0);
                        fill_data(1);
                        fill_data(2);
     // FT1,FT2 are the inputs from the dropdownlist in html

//i want it work like if i select FT1 call to fill_data(2); should be executed
//dont think of $currentsheet it is just variable it can be removed
         $currentSheet = "FT1";
                        fill_data(3);
                       
         $currentSheet = "FT2";
                        fill_data(4);
      
      $currentSheet = "FT3";
                        fill_data(5);
      fill_data(6);

                        $currentSheet = "LT1";
                        fill_data(7);
                       
        $currentSheet = "LT2";
                        fill_data(8);
      fill_data(9);
      //
```

Comment: my code i already working for me..i just want the condition in if () so that I it will work dynamically for all the tagindexes..somebody plz help me..i'm stucked on it

Comment: what error you have?

Comment: What are the values in $_POST['AI-Types']

Comment: You should indent your code properly. That wold make it so much easier to read.